# how to sort structures with string values

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, data-structures, string-comparison

I am trying to sort a dictionary in alphabetical order, which consists of structures with words followed by the meaning. When I run the program, the output for the third structure reads: <<arrow@, and the dictionary remains unsorted. I have tried a debugger but this doesnt seem to help. Thank you in advance.

```
/* program to sort a dictionary */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct entry
{
    char word [15];
    char definition [50];
};


int compareString (char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int answer;

    while (s1[i]== s2[i] && s1[i] != '\0' && s2[i] != '\0')
        ++i;

    if (s1[i] < s2[i])          // s1 < s2
        answer = -1;
    else if (s1[i]== s2[i])      //  s1 == s2
        answer = 0;
    else
        answer =1;                  // s1 > s2

    return answer;
}


void sortString (struct entry dictionary[], int entries)
{
    int compareString (char s1[], char s2[]);
    int i,j;
    int result;
    char temp[85];
    char temp2[85];

    for (i =0; i < entries; ++i)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j < entries; ++j)
        result = compareString(dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp, dictionary[i].word);
            strcpy(temp2, dictionary[i].definition);
            strcpy (dictionary[i].word, dictionary[j].word);
            strcpy (dictionary [i].definition, dictionary[j].definition);
            strcpy (dictionary[j].word, temp);
            strcpy (dictionary[j].definition, temp2);
        }
        else
        {
        continue;
        }
    }
}


int main (void)
{
    void sortString (struct entry dictionary[], int entries);
    int k;

    struct entry myDictionary [10] =
    {   {"arrdvark", "a burrowing African mammal"       },
        {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
        {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"                    },
        {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"               },
        {"agar", "a jelly made from seaweed"            },
        {"addle", "to become confused"                  },
        {"aerie", "a high nest"                         },
        {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"          },
        {"ajar", "partially opened"                     },
        {"affix", "to append; attach"                   }};


   sortString(myDictionary, 10);

   for (k =0; k <10; ++k)
   {
       printf("%s means %s\n", myDictionary[k].word, myDictionary[k].definition);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first to compare easily your strings you can use the function strcmp that is in string.h that you already include (take a look at [man strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) for more precision);

Secondary to sort your "dictionary" you can use the bubble sort algorithm which is a simple and adapted algorithm for your task : [bubble sort algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/), there is explanation and examples that can help you